# SharePoint writing to log file

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Should this be as easy as Trace.WriteInformation() in a C# file that is in a class library in the GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to your question:

SharePoint's Unified Logging Service (ULS) log files are not that easy to read. There is a browser-based viewer available over at the CodePlex [Features](http://www.codeplex.com/features) project. This adds a new link to the Central Administration Operations page that lets you pick & filter the log files.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.PortalLog.LogString("*** bmw 1 ***");
```

Comment: Only for MOSS Edition. For WSS use this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136672/programmatically-logging-to-the-sharepoint-uls